# Apache HttpClient issue

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

When I use VPN to connect to organization network I find that I am getting 401 Exception while executing the below code, though it works fine when I open the same url in any browser.

The below code works fine when I am in the network and not using VPN.

```
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
        HttpContext HTTP_CONTEXT = new BasicHttpContext();
        HTTP_CONTEXT.setAttribute(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
        HTTP_CONTEXT.setAttribute(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        request.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, HTTP_CONTEXT);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 200 || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 400) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not fetch servlet response : " + urlStr);
            LOGGER.error("Response : " + response.getStatusLine());
            throw new IOException("Got bad response, error code = " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        output = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

I have tried adding the code below but it also seems not to be working, need some guidance to get this up and running.

```
//          HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy",port);
//          DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//          httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
//
//          httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
//                  new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
//                  new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));
```

@hutingung : Detailed log for httpClient

```
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> GET /os/es/es_ES/pw/ HTTP/1.1    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> GET /os/es/es_ES/pw/ HTTP/1.1    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Host: devEnv-test.testCompanydev.com    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Host: devEnv-test.testCompanydev.com    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Connection: Keep-Alive    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> Connection: Keep-Alive    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 04:53:46 GMT[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 04:53:46 GMT[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Server: Apache[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Server: Apache[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="devEnv ACL restricted"[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="devEnv ACL restricted"[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Content-Length: 401[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Content-Length: 401[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "keep-alive: 60[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "keep-alive: 60[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "via: HTTP/1.1 proxy1783[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "via: HTTP/1.1 proxy1783[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.wire] - << "[\r][\n]"    
 [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized    
 [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 04:53:46 GMT    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 04:53:46 GMT    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Server: Apache    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Server: Apache    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="devEnv ACL restricted"    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="devEnv ACL restricted"    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Vary: Accept-Encoding    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Vary: Accept-Encoding    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Content-Length: 401    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Content-Length: 401    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << connection: keep-alive    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << connection: keep-alive    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << keep-alive: 60    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << keep-alive: 60    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << via: HTTP/1.1 proxy1783    
 [org.apache.http.headers] - << via: HTTP/1.1 proxy1783    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] - Authentication required    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] - Authentication required    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] - devEnv-test.testCompanydev.com:80 requested authentication    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] - devEnv-test.testCompanydev.com:80 requested authentication    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, Digest, Basic]    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, Digest, Basic]    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for negotiate authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for negotiate authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available    
 [org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy] - Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available    
 [com.testCompany.endeca.utils.EndecaUtils] - Could not fetch servlet response : http://devEnv-test.testCompanydev.com/os/es/es_ES/pw/    
 [com.testCompany.endeca.utils.EndecaUtils] - Response : HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized    
 [com.testCompany.endeca.utils.EndecaUtils] - Target auth scope: null    
 [com.testCompany.endeca.utils.EndecaUtils] - Target auth scheme: null    
 [com.testCompany.endeca.utils.EndecaUtils] - URL : http://devEnv-test.testCompanydev.com/os/es/es_ES/pw/    
2014-08-11 21:53:46,305 DEBUG (Finalizer) [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] - Connection 0.0.0.0:55674<->192.215.231.77:80 closed    
2014-08-11 21:53:46,305 DEBUG (Finalizer) [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] - Connection 0.0.0.0:55674<->192.215.231.77:80 closed
```

Comment: I tried using getting the Authentication scope & scheme using `AuthState targetAuthState = (AuthState) HTTP_CONTEXT.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);` but it returned null

Comment: Please post details log for HttpClient.

Comment: @hutingung : Updated my post with details HttpClient log

Comment: From the log, it shown that it manage send request to Apache Server and 401 response is from Apache Server. I suspected is the security configuration at Apache Server. First, try to use fiddler or burp to log debug http log at your browser. I suspected there might being certain authentication token. Second, check security policy at server. It might ask for authentication if request not from certain ip range. There is WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm that request authentication from client.